# Pivot with custom labels as rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add labels for each aggregate column. 
I made this SQL but I think it can be shorten.

```
select * from (
    select 'Orders' as Label, UNIT, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS 
    from PS_TABLE1
    where TRANSACTION_DATE = trunc(sysdate)-1 and UNIT in ('NYC','BOS')
)
pivot (
    SUM(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS) 
    FOR ( UNIT) IN ('BOS' as BOS,'NYC' as NYC)
)
union
select * from (
    select  'Items' as Label, UNIT,NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 
    from PS_TABLE1
    where TRANSACTION_DATE = trunc(sysdate)-1 and UNIT in ('NYC','BOS')
)
pivot (
    SUM(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS) 
    FOR ( UNIT) IN ('BOS' as BOS,'NYC' as NYC)
)
```

Results:

```
LABEL |BOS|NYC
Items |601|416
Orders|94 |79
```

I have other columns but if I use union this query will be very long. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Do your union before you pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One avenue to reshape this data is actually to `UNPIVOT` as a preliminary (to assign the desired`LABEL`s), then perform a single `PIVOT` over the expanded dataset.

This approach trades an inital row-expansion for a more succinct query -- please note, there are cost tradeoffs and performance implications here.

Here's an example with the columns you included:

--Example data setup:

```
CREATE TABLE PS_TABLE1(UNIT VARCHAR2(32), NUMBER_OF_ORDERS NUMBER, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS NUMBER, TRANSACTION_DATE DATE);

-- Target Data (a couple records to sum for BOS)
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('BOS', 25, 55, TRUNC(SYSDATE -1));
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('BOS', 10, 15, TRUNC(SYSDATE -1));
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('NYC', 250, 550, TRUNC(SYSDATE -1));
-- Other filler data 
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('BOS', 253, 785, TRUNC(SYSDATE -2));
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('NYC', 175, 315, TRUNC(SYSDATE -2));
INSERT INTO PS_TABLE1 VALUES ('DEN', 1000, 2000, TRUNC(SYSDATE -1));
```

Then query:

```
SELECT LABEL, BOS, NYC FROM (
    SELECT UNIT, LABEL, COUNT_IN_CATEGORY
    FROM (
        SELECT UNIT, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS AS ITEMS, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS AS ORDERS
        FROM PS_TABLE1
        WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1)
        -- Other columns can be added here
        UNPIVOT (COUNT_IN_CATEGORY FOR LABEL IN (ITEMS, ORDERS))
) PIVOT (SUM (COUNT_IN_CATEGORY) FOR UNIT IN ('BOS' AS BOS, 'NYC' AS NYC))
ORDER BY LABEL ASC;
```

Result:

```
    LABEL    BOS    NYC
_________ ______ ______
ITEMS         70    550
ORDERS        35    250
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this query can be shorten using case pivot method -

```
SELECT 'Items'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'BOS' THEN NUMBER_OF_ITEMS END)
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'NYC' THEN NUMBER_OF_ITEMS END)
FROM PS_TABLE1
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Orders'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'BOS' THEN NUMBER_OF_ORDERS END)
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit = 'NYC' THEN NUMBER_OF_ORDERS END)
FROM PS_TABLE1
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested)

```
with t as (
  select *
  from PS_TABLE1
  where 
    TRANSACTION_DATE = trunc(sysdate)-1
    and UNIT in ('NYC','BOS')
)

select * from (
  select 'Orders' as Label, UNIT, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS as n   
  from t
  union all
  select  'Items', UNIT, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 
  from t
)
pivot (SUM(N) FOR ( UNIT) IN ('BOS','NYC'))
```